# Como evitar o componente Chips do Materialize em branco?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, materialize

Estou usando o chips do materialize no meu projeto, mas queria evitar esse comportamento padrão de adicionar a tag mesmo vazia, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para impedir isto e inserir a tag somente quando tiver pelo menos um caractere?

O que cheguei mais próximo foi:

```
$('.chips').on('chip.add', function(e, chip){
        console.log(chip);

        var chip = chip.tag;

        if(!chip.trim()){
           alert('CHIP VAZIO!');
           //aqui gostaria de fazer algo do tipo chip.remove() porém da erro
        }
    });
```

Comment: Amigo coloca no mínimo a versão do Materialize que está usado e o seu HTML, só com a imagem não da para te ajudar muito

Comment: @hugocsl esse exemplo é do próprio materialize.

Comment: O Materialize tem muitas "falhas", pontas soltas que não foram amarradas - não sei dizer se por falta de desconhecimento ou se era objetivo deles mesmo. Parece que foi feita às pressas e de forma que ficasse visivelmente agradável. Nas `options` do seu elemento, existe a propriedade `onChipAdd`. Tente utilizá-la para validar o valor adicionado.

Comment: Na página da documentação tem o JS, eu não manjo muito, mas acredito que alguém mais experiente vai saber te ajudar https://materializecss.com/chips.html no final da página te os scrpts...

Comment: vou pesquisar melhor..

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss fiz através de on chip add, porém não encontrei nenhuma maneira de excluir este chip através do código. Sabe de algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se o nó de texto do chip está vazio utilizando o método `.trim()`. Se apenas espaços forem digitados, o trim() irá eliminá-los e tornará null o chip.

Para isso você utiliza o callback do método `onChipAdd`:

```
$('.chips').chips({
    onChipAdd: function(e, c){
      if(!c.firstChild.textContent.trim()) c.remove();
    }
});
```

O segundo parâmetro (`c`) retorna o HTML do chip criado. O primeiro nó (`firstChild`) é o texto. Se for vazio remova-o com `.remove()`.

**Teste:**

```js
$('.chips').chips({
    onChipAdd: function(e, c){
      if(!c.firstChild.textContent.trim()) c.remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="chips">
   <input class="custom-class" placeholder="Digite as tags">
</div>
```

Comment: Fiz conforme você falou, porém da esse erro:  Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined

Comment: Estou fazendo assim:   $('.chips').on('chip.add', function(e, c){
            if(!c.firstChild.textContent.trim()) c.remove();
        });

Comment: Não sei se a versão do materialize influencia, pq quando faço $('.chips').chips({)}; não reconhece...

Comment: Do jeito que vc está fazendo está entrando no `console.log(chip);`?

Comment: Sim, me retorna dessa maneira: {tag: "ksdsd"}

Comment: Qual a versão que vc está usando e como está inicializando o plugin?

Comment: Inicializo assim:  $('.chips').material_chip('data');
             
        $('.chips').material_chip(); Estou usando a versão: Materialize v0.100.2.

Comment: Use isto: `$(".chip:last").remove();`

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito obrigada!